# Schur form of a matrix and differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know of a good article on how to use the Schur form of a matrix to solve systems of differential equations?

I am learning about how to solve $y'=Ax$ types of differential equation systems using the matrix exponential ($y=y_0e^{A(t-t_0)}$). I am trying to understand how to use the Schur form of the matrix to compute the solution. I read that the eigenvalues are on the diagonal and the first column of the Schur matrix is an eigenvector... I don't know what to do next.